# Glamdring sound effect

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sound, film-sound-design

I would like to know if you have any tips to recreate the sound when Gandalf takes Glamdring (the sword at [2:17](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diPQPM0U2dA))?

Or if you have a similar resource to share?

Thank you.

Regards, Samih.

Comment: Not an answer but it's possibly either something going through a ring modulator or a sample of a metal clang put into a granular/wavetable synthesise... or a combination of the two - I must stress that this is just me guessing - you'd have to experiment to be sure

Answer (score 1):

First thing it made me think of was a passing jet [basically a dopplered white noise] with a ring-mod or flanger effect.

Answer (score 0):

For Gandalf's sword flying, I would've used the agressive, yet distinct sound of a rocket launching and using a doppler effect and ring modulation to make it less airy and more metallic. Of course it comes to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

similar to what 7HzResearch said:

- add a an OSC and make the sound slide to play the same pitch and
  modify the volume to be similar as well
- add a bitcrusher and a ring filter
- automate those effects
- distort it a little bit
- add some reverb

here is a demo

or did you mean the metal clang of the sword (any sword) itself only?